# How to add content after “#” in the url in spring MVC 3

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

How to send request to `www.MyApplication/account#tochange` in spring mvc. 
Actually in my menu there has two option, 1st change password n 2nd signup.
both option redirect to the same page `www.MyApplication/account`, which have Tab style jquery sliding form.
And the base tab is `www.MyApplication/account#tosignup`.

I just want that as click on the change password option it directly go to the `www.MyApplication/account#tochange`.

In servlet  `<a href="registration.jsp#toregister">change</a>`

What to do in Spring MVC to achieve this.

> Controller

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @RequestMapping("/account")
    public ModelAndView signup(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("registration");

        return model;
    }
```

This takes me to www.MyApplication/account. What can I do to go to www.MyApplication/account#tochange?

Comment: Do you want how to navigate on the client side using jquery between each tab or how to call spring controller when anything happens on each tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a request parameter to your URL. The URL will look like `/account?action=[register|changepassword]`. Send a flag from controller to front end like `option=register|changepassword` and then assign the active class (or tab index) based on the option.